# Summary data by column in R

Tags: r, summarize

I have the following data

```
pt_id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
Tob_pk <- c(2, 5, 7, 1, 8, 12, 14, 3, 6, 8, 10, 20, 13, 5, 4, 12, 10)
Tobacco <- c("Once","Twice","Never", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,"Once","Twice","Quit","Once",NA,NA,"Never", NA, "Never")
Alcohol <- c("Twice", "Once",NA, NA, "Never", NA, NA, "Once", NA, "Quit", "Twice", NA, "Once", NA, NA, "Never", "Never")
PA <- c("Once",NA,"Never", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,"Once",NA,"Quit","Once",NA,NA,"Never", NA, NA)
mydata <- data.frame(pt_id, Tob_pk, Tobacco, Alcohol, PA)
mydata
```

I want the summary/ proportions for each variable in my dataset, I tried using the following code to get the summary/ proportions for each variable

```
data_summ <- mydata %>%
  summarize_at(.vars=3:5, funs(prop.table(.)))
```

However, I am getting the following error

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `Tobacco`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
ℹ Input `Tobacco` is `prop.table(Tobacco)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. It would be helpful if I could get any suggestions to get the following output but with the percentage of NA's too.

```
Tobacco                   Alcohol                        PA

Never    0.3333333      Never    0.3333333       Never    0.3333333  
Once     0.3333333      Once     0.3333333       Once     0.5000000
Quit     0.1111111      Quit     0.1111111       Quit.    0.1666667
Twice    0.2222222      Twice    0.2222222
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `base`

```r
pt_id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
Tob_pk <- c(2, 5, 7, 1, 8, 12, 14, 3, 6, 8, 10, 20, 13, 5, 4, 12, 10)
Tobacco <- c("Once","Twice","Never", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,"Once","Twice","Quit","Once",NA,NA,"Never", NA, "Never")
Alcohol <- c("Twice", "Once",NA, NA, "Never", NA, NA, "Once", NA, "Quit", "Twice", NA, "Once", NA, NA, "Never", "Never")
PA <- c("Once",NA,"Never", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,"Once",NA,"Quit","Once",NA,NA,"Never", NA, NA)
mydata <- data.frame(pt_id, Tob_pk, Tobacco, Alcohol, PA)

apply(mydata[3:5], 2, function(x) prop.table(table(x, useNA="ifany")))
$Tobacco
x
     Never       Once       Quit      Twice       <NA> 
0.17647059 0.17647059 0.05882353 0.11764706 0.47058824 

$Alcohol
x
     Never       Once       Quit      Twice       <NA> 
0.17647059 0.17647059 0.05882353 0.11764706 0.47058824 

$PA
x
     Never       Once       Quit       <NA> 
0.11764706 0.17647059 0.05882353 0.64705882
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

using `tidyverse`

```r
library(tidyverse)
map_dfr(mydata[3:5], ~prop.table(table(.x))) 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Never     Once      Quit      Twice    
#>   <table>   <table>   <table>   <table>  
#> 1 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.1111111 0.2222222
#> 2 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.1111111 0.2222222
#> 3 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.1666667        NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the help! In my original dataset, I have almost 35 variables/ columns and some are "dbl" variable and not character variables. Is there a way I can skip those columns with "dbl" variables in my code without having to select a range (eg., 3:5 and then 8:5) manually?

Comment: And can we export the output from base R code into an excel file?

Comment: try it like this `map_dfr(.x = select(mydata, where(is.character)), .f =  prop.table(table(.x)))`

Comment: for `base` `cols_char <- sapply(mydata, is.character)`
`apply(mydata[, cols_char], 2, function(x) prop.table(table(x, useNA="ifany")))`

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mydata %>%
  select(3:5) %>%
  gather('Your_vice', 'freq', 1:3) %>%
  group_by(Your_vice, freq) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(perc = n/sum(n))

df

# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   Your_vice [3]
   Your_vice freq      n   perc
   <chr>     <chr> <int>  <dbl>
 1 Alcohol   Never     3 0.176 
 2 Alcohol   Once      3 0.176 
 3 Alcohol   Quit      1 0.0588
 4 Alcohol   Twice     2 0.118 
 5 Alcohol   NA        8 0.471 
 6 PA        Never     2 0.118 
 7 PA        Once      3 0.176 
 8 PA        Quit      1 0.0588
 9 PA        NA       11 0.647 
10 Tobacco   Never     3 0.176 
11 Tobacco   Once      3 0.176 
12 Tobacco   Quit      1 0.0588
13 Tobacco   Twice     2 0.118 
14 Tobacco   NA        8 0.471
```

Answer (score 1):

You could transform the variables to factors with corresponding levels. Then `table` with option `useNA="ifany"` displays the `NA`.

```
mydata[3:5] <- lapply(mydata[3:5], factor, levels=c("Never", "Once", "Quit", "Twice"))
res1 <- sapply(mydata[3:5], function(x) prop.table(table(x)))
res1
#         Tobacco   Alcohol        PA
# Never 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
# Once  0.3333333 0.3333333 0.5000000
# Quit  0.1111111 0.1111111 0.1666667
# Twice 0.2222222 0.2222222 0.0000000

res2 <- sapply(mydata[3:5], function(x) prop.table(table(x, useNA="ifany")))
res2
#          Tobacco    Alcohol         PA
# Never 0.17647059 0.17647059 0.11764706
# Once  0.17647059 0.17647059 0.17647059
# Quit  0.05882353 0.05882353 0.05882353
# Twice 0.11764706 0.11764706 0.00000000
# <NA>  0.47058824 0.47058824 0.64705882
```

Comment: Can the output be exported to excel file? I tried using ```write.xlsx(res2, file = "myDATA.xlsx", sheetName = "res2", col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE, append = FALSE)``` but it's not working!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `prop.table` + `table` + `na.omit` + `factor`

```
do.call(
  cbind,
  lapply(
    mydata[3:5],
    function(x) {
      prop.table(
        table(
          na.omit(
            factor(x, levels = unique(na.omit(unlist(mydata[3:5]))))
          )
        )
      )
    }
  )
)
```

which gives

```
        Tobacco   Alcohol        PA
Once  0.3333333 0.3333333 0.5000000
Twice 0.2222222 0.2222222 0.0000000
Never 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
Quit  0.1111111 0.1111111 0.1666667
```